# Is it useful to transfer Ruby model methods to the service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

At the moment, I have many methods in ruby models and it is difficult to check them. Can I write a management service and call each of the methods in a separate service?

```rb
class Manager
  def call(params:)
    @params = params
    
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      service_a
      service_b
      service_c
    end
  end

private

  def service_a
    ServiceA.call(params: @params)
  end

  def service_b
    ServiceB.call(params: @params)
  end

  def service_c
    ServiceC.call(params: @params)
  end
end
```

and how can I use our service in Ruby **model**

Comment: If ServiceA etc inherit from ActiveRecord, then you can do it. Have you tried it? What happened? Mostly people here don't ask "can I do... " but instead say "I tried this and I'm getting this error, why do you think it is?".

Comment: Well, there are soooo many patterns around this. The one I am a bit fan of is a bit edge - there should be no business logic in "models". At all. None. Not even validations. ActiveRecord is not even a model - it is a database interface and nothing else, promoting it to a domain model is at the heart of 99% of issues with rails applications. So yes, move those methods out into separate service object, but don't bother wrappiong them in model methods, just use those services in your code.

Comment: In case someone claim my approach is mad - here's Uncle Bob's article on the topic: https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/active-record-vs-objects